# How do i integrate my create new post url ,with detail view and list view so that users can create new post on the same page like that of facebook

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

What am trying to accomplish is for users to be able to create post and add pictures as on Facebook, but somehow in Django am having a challenge with that, create post has to be on a separate URL as detail and list view has separate URLs how do I integrate all of the URL to be on one template, so that every post works on one page like that of Facebook.

[image]

```
here is my views...

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'feed/feed.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            liked = [i for i in Post.objects.all() if Like.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, post=i)]
            context['liked_post'] = liked
        return context
```

```
class UserPostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'feed/feed.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserPostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username.get_full_name'))
        liked = [i for i in Post.objects.filter(user_name=user) if Like.objects.filter(user = self.request.user, post=i)]
        context['liked_post'] = liked
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username.get_full_name'))
        return Post.objects.filter(user_name=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

```
@login_required
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    user = request.user
    comments = post.comments.filter()
    is_liked =  Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
    new_comment = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post
            new_comment.username = user
            new_comment.save()
            return redirect('feed', pk=pk)
    else:
        comment_form = NewCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'feed/feed.html', {'post':post,
                         'comments':comments,
                         "new_comment":new_comment,
                         'is_liked':is_liked,
                          'comment_form':comment_form})

@login_required
def create_post(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.user_name = user
            data.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Posted Successfully')
            return redirect('feed')
    else:
        form = NewPostForm()
    return render(request, 'feed/feed.html', {'form':form})

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['description', 'pic', 'tags']
    template_name = 'feed/feed.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_name.get_full_name = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.user_name.get_full_name:
            return True
        return False
```

Here are my Urls..

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='feed'),
    path('post/new/', views.create_post, name='post-create'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='feed'),
    path('like/', views.like, name='post-like'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', views.post_delete, name='post-delete'),
    path('search_posts/', views.search_posts, name='search_posts'),
    path('user_posts/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like SPA (single page application)? If so, you need to look at front-end javascript web frameworks.

Comment: Know it's not an SPA , Am actually creating a social media app like Facebook with Django and what am trying to accomplish is for users to able to create post on the same page as  where the detail page and list page would all be at the same place. You know with Django i need to separate the URLs when you click on create new post it takes you to the create new post URL, but that's not what i want, i want every thing to be at the same place. Hope am clear enough?